# How to change "Product" to "Service" in new order WooCommerce email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

My request sounds easy, but I'm not able to configure it. I want to change the word "**product**" in the new order email the customers received to "**service**".. as we are offering services, not products.

I downloaded a plugin called "Say What?" but I should get the exact text domain, which I did not find.

I tried too apply the following filter but it did not work too

```php
add_filter( 'admin-new-order', '__return_false' );
 
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'PRODUCT' :
            $translated_text = __( 'SERVICE', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`emails/email-order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php) template file, line [42](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php#L42)

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php`.

Replace

```
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

With

```
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Service', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

Comment: I don't see this email email-order-details.php .. I have like customer-invoice and its structure is totally different than the one u sent me. Should I create new php file and just copy and paste the above codes and change what i want?

Comment: Please read [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: as my products are appointments, I edited this file " customer-appointment-confirmed.php " and changed the product column to service but nothing changes

Comment: Your question is about 'new order woocommerce email', The file you are talking about is not present in WooCommerce by default. Your question has therefore been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nishant_wc_translations($translated){
    $text = array(
    'Product' => 'Service',
    'Products' => 'Services',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}
```

add this in functions.php